# How to check state onKeypress

Tags: javascript, key, state, keypress, onkeypress

I have simpy question..

How can take a state key (keydown, keyup) in onkeypress in Javascript?

```
document.onkeypress = function()
{
  console.log(/* STATE (down or up sometihn like this*/)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you have 2 functions? (up and down)

```
document.getElementById('my').onkeydown = function() {

    console.log('down');

}

document.getElementById('my').onkeyup = function() {
    console.log('up');
}
```